# Lower and Upper Bound in case of Decreasing/Non-ascending vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, lower-bound, upperbound

I understood the concept of Lower and Upper found for an Increasing/Ascending array.
i.e

1. Lower Bound: iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) >= Value
2. Upper Bound:
   iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) > Value

Below is my code for Decreasing/Non-ascending vector in which I am facing issue:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = {45,40,35,12,6,3};

    auto itr3 = lower_bound(vec.begin(),vec.end(),40);
    auto itr4 = upper_bound(vec.begin(),vec.end(),40);

    if(itr3 == vec.end() && itr4 == vec.end())
        cout<<"Lower & Upper Bound not Found\n";
    else
    {
        cout <<"lower Bound of 40 :"<<*itr3<<endl;
        cout <<"Upper Bound of 40 :"<<*itr4<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The Output is:

```
Lower & Upper Bound not Found.
```

But as mentioned above the output should be something like :

```
lower Bound of 40 :40
Upper Bound of 40 :45
```

Please help me understood his behavior of lower and upper bound in case of decreasing/non-ascending vectors.

Comment: `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` depend on a specific order. By default, it's that of `std::less()` for the data type. Your vector explicitily doesn't provide this. Either, use it backwards (i.e. `rbegin()` and `rend()`) or provide a custom predicate which reflects the order you've chosen.

Answer (score 4):

The target of [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) have to be increasing (non-decreasing) order.

You can change the definition of "increasing" by specifying a comparator by the 4th argument of the functions.

You can use [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) to work with descending vectors.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = {45,40,35,12,6,3};

    auto itr3 = lower_bound(vec.begin(),vec.end(),40,std::greater<int>());
    auto itr4 = upper_bound(vec.begin(),vec.end(),40,std::greater<int>());

    if(itr3 == vec.end() && itr4 == vec.end())
        cout<<"Lower & Upper Bound not Found\n";
    else
    {
        cout <<"lower Bound of 40 :"<<*itr3<<endl;
        cout <<"Upper Bound of 40 :"<<*itr4<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use reverse iterators to get the 40/45 result:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> const vec = { 45, 40, 35, 12, 6, 3 };

  auto const it_lb = std::lower_bound(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), 40);
  auto const it_ub = std::upper_bound(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), 40);

  std::printf("Lower: %d\nUpper: %d\n", *it_lb, *it_ub);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another overloaded declarations of the algorithms `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` with a comparison function as for example the standard function object `std::greater`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 45, 40, 35, 12, 6, 3 };
    
    auto lower_bound = std::lower_bound( std::begin( vec ),
                                         std::end( vec ),
                                         40,
                                         std::greater<int>() );

    auto upper_bound = std::upper_bound( std::begin( vec ),
                                         std::end( vec ),
                                         40,
                                         std::greater<int>() );
                                         
    std::cout << *lower_bound << " <-> " << *upper_bound << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
40 <-> 35
```

I have not checked the returned iterators in the program whether they are equal to the iterator returned by `std::end( vec )` for simplicity.

Instead of the standard function object `std::greater` you can use your own lambda-expression. For example

```
auto descending = []( const auto &x, const auto &y )
                  {
                    return y < x;
                  };
                  
auto lower_bound = std::lower_bound( std::begin( vec ),
                                     std::end( vec ),
                                     40,
                                     descending );

auto upper_bound = std::upper_bound( std::begin( vec ),
                                     std::end( vec ),
                                     40,
                                     descending );
```